# Sunrise and Sunset Calculator

Tags: java, date, time

I am trying to get Sunrise and Sunset time for Phoenix.

I am using : https://github.com/mikereedell/sunrisesunsetlib-java

```
    package sunriseSunsetCalculator;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

    import com.luckycatlabs.sunrisesunset.SunriseSunsetCalculator;
    import com.luckycatlabs.sunrisesunset.dto.Location;

    public class getSunriseSunet 
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
            Location location = new Location("33.4500", "-112.0667");
            SunriseSunsetCalculator calculator = new SunriseSunsetCalculator(location, "Phoenix");

            Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

            String officialSunrise = calculator.getOfficialSunriseForDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            String officialSunset = calculator.getOfficialSunriseForDate(Calendar.getInstance());

            System.out.println(today + " officialSunrise : " + officialSunrise);
            System.out.println(today + " officialSunset  : " + officialSunset);
        }
    }
```

output

Sat Mar 14 21:35:51 MST 2015 officialSunrise : 13:39

Sat Mar 14 21:35:51 MST 2015 officialSunset  : 13:39

Any suggestion why the Sunrise and Sunset time are incorrect ?

Comment: You use `getOfficialSunriseForDate()` in **both** calls.  Are you supposed to pass just a `Calendar` instance to it?

Comment: Are you located in Phoenix?

Comment: Thanks that was a typo.
Yes, the method needs Calendar instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if your timeZoneIdentifier for Phoenix is correct. Could you please change it to: **America/Phoenix**

Also you Calendar should be created in the correct time zone:

```
SunriseSunsetCalculator calculator = new SunriseSunsetCalculator(lcation, "US/Phoenix");
Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Phoenix"));
String sunrise = calculator.getOfficialSunriseForDate(today);
String sunset  = calculator.getOfficialSunsetForDate(today);
```

Comment: I should have used "US/Arizona".

    SunriseSunsetCalculator calculator = new SunriseSunsetCalculator(location, "US/Arizona");
    Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Arizona"));
      
    String officialSunrise = calculator.getOfficialSunriseForDate(today);
    String officialSunset = calculator.getOfficialSunsetForDate(today);

I get the right results.

 officialSunrise : 06:39
 officialSunset  : 18:36


Time Zones: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html

Date and time: http://www.timeanddate.com/sun/usa/phoenix

Comment: Phoenix is a major city so you can use both `US/Phoenix` as city or `US/Arizona` as state location. As long as you stay away from the mountain time (which could create a daytime-saving time issue), you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the sunset time, call `getOfficialSunsetForDate(Calendar.getInstance());`

Comment: You are awesome, for catching my typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
package sunriseSunsetCalculator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import com.luckycatlabs.sunrisesunset.SunriseSunsetCalculator;
import com.luckycatlabs.sunrisesunset.dto.Location;

    public class getSunriseSunet 
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
            Location location = new Location("33.4500", "-112.0667");

            SunriseSunsetCalculator calculator = new SunriseSunsetCalculator(location, "US/Arizona");
            Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Arizona"));

            String officialSunrise = calculator.getOfficialSunriseForDate(today);
            String officialSunset = calculator.getOfficialSunsetForDate(today);

            System.out.println(" officialSunrise : " + officialSunrise);
            System.out.println(" officialSunset  : " + officialSunset);

        }
    }
```

Get Time Zones from : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html

Output:

officialSunrise : 06:39

officialSunset  : 18:36